# Set a C++ bitset from a binary input steam

Tags: c++, bit

I have an input stream from a binary file. I want to create a bitset for the first 5 bits of the stream. Here is the code I have so far:

```
ifstream is;    
is.open ("bin_file.out", ios::binary );

bitset<5> first_five_bits;

is >> first_five_bits; // always is set to default 00000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char c;
if( ! cin.get(c) ) throw ROFL();  // return error, flip bit, call mom
bitset<5> first_five_bits(c >> (CHAR_BIT-5));  // CHAR_BIT in <climits>
```

Comment: Will this populate  with the first five bits or bytes?

Comment: First five bytes. If you want the first five bits then bit-manipulate the input.

Comment: Updated the answer to grab the first five bits. Removed the sample code for grabbing the first five bytes.

Comment: Thanks! How would this change if the bit endianness was big? I am guessing it would be just first_five_bits(c). Is that correct?

Comment: @Jon: I don't think there is such a thing as bit endianness, eventhough on PPC-registers, they start counting from the msb to the lsb.  All systems I know have the msb as first bit.  But checking this doesn't harm.

Answer (score 1):

Streams don't work with bits, so you should read in a byte and set that to the bitset.

Not compiled, not tested:

```
char c;
is >> c;
bitset<5> first_five_bits(c >> 3);
```

Comment: `operator>>()` formats the input. It will skip whitespace, manipulate the input bits in the case of ASCII numbers etc.

Comment: @wilhelm agreed: the cin.get(c) from your answer is better here.  I mainly wanted to point out that streams work with bytes, not bits.